# Confused about whether or not I should use the ratio test on a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wanted to apply the ratio test on the following series:
**$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+3}{(k+2)!}$$**

However, I didn't get the limit that was provided in the solution which is:
**$$2e-3$$**

So far, I got the following but now I'm stuck and I'm not sure how I can still get a solution that contains "e" as I've already canceled out the factorial:

**$$\frac{(k+4)*(k+2)!}{(k+3)*(k+3)!} = \frac{(k+4)*2}{(k+3)*(k+3)} = ...$$**

I would really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: No, I didn't notice it, to be honest - it's fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided value is not the result of the ratio-convergence-test but the one of the whole series.

Indeed what you have done is correct (up to a 2 in the numerator), and you can notice that by taking the limit for $k\to\infty$ the fraction goes to $0$, thus the test is conclusive and tells you that the series indeed converges.

Now to compute the series, notice that
$$\frac{k+3}{(k+2)!}=\frac{k+2+1}{(k+2)!}=\frac{k+2}{(k+2)!}+\frac{1}{(k+2)!}=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}+\frac{1}{(k+2)!}$$
which you can then compare with the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=e$